# How to forward a mail server without MX records?

Tags: email, email-server, g-suite, mx-record, imap

My company is switching from an old clunky dedicated email server (which we can't maintain anymore) to Google Apps email, and we'd like to start using the Google email now, as the old server regularly loses emails.

The problem is that we're waiting on the MX records to change, and the guy before me (who's no longer with the company) set the TTL to a ridiculously high number (like a week) thinking that it would improve server performance.

While we wait on the MX change to propagate, I was wondering if there's any way I can set the old server to just forward all connections to google instead.

Is there any way to do that?

**EDIT**

I'm using Postfix/Dovecot on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server (The last guy upgraded the server before he left, but it's still not working well and we don't have anyone with email server experience to maintain it.)

Comment: `Is there any way to do that?` - Yes.  Now, that you have your answer, perhaps you would like to add some more details about your existing mail setup so someone could give you more useful information.  For example, what is your current mail server?

Comment: If it's losing email, why do you think using it to forward email will be somehow more resilient?

Comment: @Zoredache I've edited with some details. Do I need to put anything else?

Comment: @mfinni I don't really know. Misguided optimism I suppose. This was really more of an administration decision than an IT one.

Comment: I am not familiar with postfix.  But I would start looking at the documents for setting up a relay.  http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html  You basically need to switch from your current setup over to a relay.  You want to relay only for your domain, and you want to your domain to be relayed to Google.

Comment: Also see the routing section in the Google Apps Docs.  It will have the information about addresses and such to route to.  https://support.google.com/a/topic/2921034?hl=en&ref_topic=14867

Answer (score 1):

Set up the old box to be a **secondary MX** server, flush the DNS records on your old box (so that when you do a 'host -t MX your domain' you see google with a lower MX value than your old box).  Now your old email box *may* merrily be a secondary MX server and relay email to google.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record#The_backup_MX

Comment: But won't those MX Records take just as long to propagate?

Comment: Simply adding an MX record won't change a mail server that is currently configured to accept all mail for a given domain over to relaying mail for that domain.  Also in this case the external people are all ready getting to the old MX record which is presumably his existing postfix box.  He doesn't have to add another MX record for the messages to get to the postfix box.  He just needs to get the messages from his postfix box over to Google.

Answer (score 0):

Just forward port 25 on the (retired) mailserver to Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a postfix server to forward all email to another server with the line:

relayhost = googlehostname.google.com

To answer the specific question that was asked "How to send email to an address and not an MX record", you can edit the /etc/postfix/transport file to over email locations for a domain.

Something like:

example.com smtp:googlehostname.google.com:587

Then rebuilding the file with
  postmap hash:/etc/postfix/transport
and restarting postfix

will cause your postfix server to forward all email for example.com to googlehostname.google.com on port 587 without doing an MX lookup. This is how you can build internal processing servers without having to muck with fake DNS.